# A Puzzling Christmas Card

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, seasonal

I just got an interesting Christmas card from my cousin, with a very strange front.

> Hey Sconibulus, I heard you liked puzzles so I thought you might have fun with this, the shopkeep guy said something about making circles around the numbers to get a hidden message for your campus square?
>
> I hope you're having a good Christmas, and don't eat all the cookies too quickly!

I don't think the bit about the cookies is relevant to the puzzle, it just came with a box of very tasty cookies, (that are sadly gone now) but it's been included for completeness.

[image: Octagons and Squares with Numbers]

Comment: Looks like some sort of Minesweeper variant ...

Comment: The thing I've seen elsewhere with this sort of layout is a different class of puzzle, but when I try to solve this one as one I get a contradiction. Might just be a blunder on my part.

Comment: ... I get the same contradiction twice in a row, so it looks as if my conjecture about what sort of puzzle might underlie this is wrong.

Comment: Oops, my editing from an older version of the puzzle wasn't entirely correct, the top-left green octagon is supposed to read 2, while the 3 in the square right of the bottom-right green octagon is supposed to be blank, with the 3 immediately below. I'm working on correcting the image now.

Comment: Well, now I've solved it but I'm clearly missing some further cleverness...

Answer (score 3):

If we treat the image as a

> Slitherlink/Loopy puzzle

and solve it, we get this (apologies for my excessive neatness and elegance :-); the blue annotations are because I was working from an earlier version of the image):

> [image]

but right now I'm failing to see any hidden message in it...

It's obvious to guess that

> the green octagons are particularly significant; perhaps e.g. the presence or absence of portions of their edge might indicate 1 or 0 bits in ASCII or something. (It definitely can't be that specific thing. ASCII is a 7-bit code and each of the eight edge positions occurs in both states.)

Nothing of this sort jumps out at me right now, though.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your browser.  Obviously you need to clear your cookies.  I mean, he mentioned the cookies are gone right there in the puzzle story.  Glad to help. `:)`